# Updating mongo collection

Tags: c++, mongodb

I use mongodb and c++ driver for it and
when I update some collection of documents with fields *entid, div, name, fld2* using this code:

```
connection.update("mydb.mycol", Query(bob().append("entid",1).obj()), bob().append("div", 5).obj());
```

updating has been done successfully, but updated document has not *entid*, *name* and *fld2* fields. How can I update document without missing fields I do not need to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [$set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) [modifier](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations). I don't know anything about the C++ driver but the JS syntax is:

```
db.mydb.update({"entid" : 1}, {"$set" : {"div" : 5}})
```

I hope you can transform this to C++ code ;)